# Get number of friends use my facebook app

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk

How to get number of friends who are already using my facebook app.

I can get the all the friends who are using the app by using `me/friends` and i can get the total friends count as `total_count`,

now can i get the total number of friends who already using the app. i can count the result from `me/friends` and get the `total`, but is there anything nicer?

```
$request = new FacebookRequest(
        $session,
        'GET',
        '/me/friends'
);
$response = $request->execute();
$g_object = $response->getGraphObject();
```

`$g_object` => contains the `all the friends who are already using the app` and `users friend count`